# Error - Cannot find resource named 'ComboBoxFocusVisual'

Tags: wpf, combobox, blend

I am trying to add a Resource dictionary for ComboBox and am getting this error after I applied the stlye (the style won't work/show):

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find resource named
>   'ComboBoxFocusVisual'. Resource names are case sensitive.

What could have gone wrong? I tried reloading the project and building it.

This is my code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxx" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                        <Border CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}" x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="#50FFFFFF" Height="100" d:IsHidden="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer" Foreground="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" OpacityMask="#FFFBFBFB"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                    <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

```
     <ResourceDictionary Source="C:\Users\PID Projekt I5\Desktop\SendMe\ArduinoSMS_sender\Resource Dictionary\ComboBoxx.xaml"/>
```

Comment: Where is define all your StaticResource ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but my files are in a subfile in the Solution. Every other Resource dictionary works

Answer (score 0):

Add the following missing style above your ComboBox style:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You will of course need to define the "ButtonNormalBackground", "ButtonNormalBorder" and all other resources that you are referencing as well. You should be able to get these from the same place where you did get the style...

Comment: How come those styles are missing? This is the first time this happened

Comment: Okay I think thats because I defined those style in application scope in Blend

Comment: "How come those styles are missing?" - Because you didn't add them to your ResourceDictionary...you *must* define all resources that you are using somewhere in scope.

Comment: Added all styles and still didn't work. Then I added references from PresentationFoundation.Aero and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was frustrated by a similar error and found that the SEQUENCE in which resources are defined is of the essence. You need to make sure that you define lowest level resources that are then referred to in other resources (e.g. colors) at the top of your resource file.